# Unable to format newline comments?

Tags: support, comments, formatting

Enter/Newline is not working (two spaces at end) with comments?

Because other formatting working. Do I miss something?

Comment: Hmmm, it is in fact so... I think this [rule](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/editing-help#linebreaks) belongs to the answer format, not to the comments.

Comment: But I can use other formating like this : **format** _format2_ `format3`. EDIT : just cant use the newline formatting.  why?

Comment: You also can't do blockquotes. `>` does nothing. You can use `\`` backtick formatting though. None of \n, <br> <br /> work.

Comment: Any particular reason why?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this has always been the way of comments on SE sites. It's annoying (especially for code in comments) but then a general policy of the network is to *avoid* extended discussion. I think having a little nasty formatting like this actually dissuades people from getting bogged down in the comments and makes you think about posting an actual answer or editing something that's already in place.

Comment: well now that you put it this way, it sorta makes sense. put useful info in answers, not comments.